# React-sortable-tree node height increment issue

Tags: reactjs

I have two nodes in react-sortable-tree as depicted in the image. By default the row height provided by the package is around 61px, if i increase the size of the row to 84px then the two rows gets intersected, is there any way out. I tried manipulating the css but couldnt find the solution yet...

Css styling i applied was

```
.rstcustom__rowWrapper {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    height: 84px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: move;
}
```

The row when the height is increased
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<SortableTree
      ...
      treeData={state}
      rowHeight={}// multiple of base height for example
      generateNodeProps={({ node, path }) => {
      ...
```

rowHeight as props in your SortableTree components.
Avoid changing directly the CSS, use the: style, rowHeight, innerStyle props as described in the [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sortable-tree#props)